# Accessing switch case arguments in default case in swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement, alamofire

I have an URLRequestConvertible enum (AlamoFire), with cases

`getId(String), 
getList(String, String), 
getFullList(String, String)`
and so on.

In the

```
public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
```

method, I need to access the 1st argument which is common for all the cases. 
I would like to know if it accessible in default case or is there any way to mention all the cases in a generic way. like variable in tuples.

For now I am accessing the argument like

```
var headerValue : String {

    switch self {

    case .getId(let value):
        return value
    case .getList(let value, _):
        return value
    case .getFullList(let value, _):
        return value
    }
}
```

Am expecting something like

```
case let check(let value, _): return value
```

Any suggestion are welcome on how do I handle it from here

Answer (score 1):

You can at least simplify it slightly to

```
var headerValue : String {
    switch self {
    case .getId(let value),
         .getList(let value, _),
         .getFullList(let value, _):
        return value
    }
}
```

since all cases bind the same variable with the same type.